# Is there a way to clean output on command prompt programmatically?

Tags: python

Is there a way to programmatically clean output on command prompt? I want to be able to print each letter of a word than erase them one at a time in the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

def show(word):
  for char in word:
    stdout.write(char)
    stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)
  for char in word:
    stdout.write('\b \b')
    stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)

show('hello')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
os.system('clear')
```

Works on linux.

You'll have to add:

```
import os
```

And for windows:

```
os.system('CLS')
```

Answer (score 0):

With [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is very easy you only have to do this:

```
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.call('clear')
except:
    subprocess.call('cls')
```